# Understanding "бы"

Tags: значения, словоупотребление

The question might be too broad, anyway:

1. Which use cases (phrases) are there for ***бы*** **besides when it has this kind of subjunctive meaning coming with a verb ending in `-л / -ла / -ло / -ли`** (see below)?

   - For instance: *как бы*, *почему бы и нет*

_2. What function does **бы** have, i. e. does it always make something "unreal" (subjunctive)?

- For instance: What's the difference between saying

  - *почему нет* and
  - *почему **бы и** нет*?

What I mentioned in 1. (..coming with a verb..) are the following use cases

> **бы**
>   **1**. употребляется для образования сослагательного наклонения
>   1) предположительной возможности
>   *кто бы это мог быть? — who could / might that be?*
>   2) вежливого пожелания, совета, просьбы
>   *было бы очень приятно вас видеть — it would be very nice to see you*
>
> **2**. (+ ни) употребляется в составе неопределённых местоимений и союзов
>   *кто бы ни пришёл — whoever comes*
>   *что бы из этого ни вышло — whatever comes of it*
>   *что бы ни случилось — whatever happens*
>   <sub>Ref: D. I. Yermolovich, T. M. Krasavina</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Почему нет?** may mean *why (something) is missing?*, or (another meaning) *what objections do you have?*:

> -- У нас нет воды.
>   -- Почему нет?
>   -- Авария - труба лопнула.
>
> -- Ты пойдешь в театр?
>   -- Нет.
>   -- Почему нет?
>   -- Очень плохо себя чувствую.

**Почему бы и нет?** has exactly the same meaning as **why not?**. It is not for asking about objections, it's an invitation to look at the alternative solutions.

I would say that **бы** is a word for possibilities and alternatives. This also includes polite forms - by using **бы** you allow other person either to agree with you (accept your proposal) or to make own decision. Without **бы** it may sound like you are forcing other person to accept what you want.

As for other examples of using бы, here is what *Большой толковый словарь* proposes:

> БЫ; Б
>
> 1. Указывает на условно-предположительную возможность действия. *Мог бы полюбить. На твоём месте поступил бы иначе. Будто бы твой. Были бы друзья - нашёл бы куда пойти. Если б не ты - мне не жить.*
> 2. Указывает на желательность или долженствование действия. *Поохотиться бы по-настоящему! Чайку бы сейчас! Потише бы! Ей бы большую семью иметь. Были бы все здоровые. Покрапал бы дождичек! Ты бы хоть позвонил!*
> 3. Указывает на вежливо-предупредительное пожелание кому-л., совет, предложение. *Ты бы прилёг. Сходить бы тебе к врачу. Может, поговорил бы с начальством?*
> 4. (обычно с отриц.). *Указывает на опасение чего-л. Не опоздать бы. Не кусать бы потом локти. Лишь бы не дурак. Туфли любые, лишь бы не белые.*
> 5. (в придат. предл.). Указывает на обусловленность действия. *Не было бы счастья, да несчастье помогло (Погов.).*
> 6. (в составе сложных союзов, частиц и нареч.). Указывает на различные оттенки условности, предположительности, желаемости действия. *Будто бы, если бы, как бы, хоть бы, хоть бы и так, хоть бы хны, хоть бы что, ещё бы, во что бы то ни стало и т.п.*

Comment: _Почему бы нет?_ and _почему нет?_ are not really the same and may have different meanings depending on the context.  The first one expresses more of a certainty around the "yes" part.  The second one can be genuinely asking about why not, with emphasis on either of the two words.

Answer (score 3):

"Бы" is pretty close to "would". Я бы сказал = I would say.